# Component Development - Custom Admin Menu Link

Tags: administrator

I have a component listed on the JED that I am currently updating to fix a bug. I noticed however that when creating a custom Administrator menu in the backend, my component does not show up in the list of available installed components to create a link from. I was wondering what I need to change in my extension XML file so that my component shows up in that component list.

To reproduce the issue:

Create an Administrator menu in the backend
Add a new menu item
When selecting the Menu Item Type a list opens of available components

The Menu Item Type list is where I am trying to get me component to show.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work in the same way as creating front end menu item types, but with your `default.xml` file being saved under an administrator view rather than a front end view.

For example, com_content adds the featured articles link under `administrator/com_content/views/featured/default.xml`

This file contains the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_CONTENT_FEATURED_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>
            <![CDATA[COM_CONTENT_FEATURED_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC]]>
        </message>
    </layout>
</metadata>
```

Adding the same (changing only the title and message) to your component's administrator view(s) should make it/them appear under Menu Item Type.

Com_content is using translations, as any JED component should, but you could easily test this by replacing `COM_CONTENT_FEATURED_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE` with dummy text.

Comment: I am going to try this out today @Richard B. I will let you know if it solved my problem.

Comment: Yep. This was the correct answer. Great solution and thanks Richard B.

Answer (score 1):

I use Component Creator to create all my components in the first instance so my answer is related to the way they code components to a large degree.
I've personally never created an Admin menu item before so I had to see if my components actually let me do this, and it did.  So in the main manifest XML you will need to have a menu and perhaps a submenu element defined and I'm hoping that the following example of code helps.

```
    <administration>
    <menu img="../media/com_mycomponent/images/s_com_mycomponent.png" >COM_MYCOMPONENT</menu>
    <submenu>
        <menu link="option=com_mycomponent&amp;view=clientadverts" view="clientadverts" img="../media/com_mycomponent/images/s_clientadverts.png" alt="Mycomponent/Clientadverts">COM_MYCOMPONENT_TITLE_ADVERTS</menu>
        <menu link="option=com_categories&amp;extension=com_mycomponent" view="categories" img="../media/com_mycomponent/images/s_clientadverts.png" alt="Mycomponent/Categories">COM_MYCOMPONENT_ADVERTS_ADVERT_TYPE</menu>
    </submenu>
```

Cheers
Glenn

Comment: Yep. All of my components have the admin and submenu elements defined in the manifest.

Comment: This method works if you re-zip and reinstall your extension I found out well after the fact.